# Why doesn't Recversion always change on record update?

Tags: axapta

I found this question on the old Dynamics AX forum and found the answer.
I was not able to post it there due to Microsoft currently is forcing all to start using their new 365 version

"I've noticed that Recversion on some records in the database aren't updating as I'd expect.  What I'm trying to do is to rework how my company is moving data into our Data Warehouse for reporting purposes.  Up until this point, the tables we use for reports are refreshed each night with data from our production environment.  Data Warehouse tables are truncated, then reloaded fresh.

Naturally, as our production database grows, this is becoming less and less ideal.  We're using SQL Server 2005 for our database, so we don't have access to the new SQL "Merge" statement, but we were able to achieve a similar effect.  We match records between the databases by RecId, and are using Recversion to test whether a Data Warehouse record needs to be updated from production in the case of changes to the record (inserts are handled based on not finding a matching record in the data warehouse by RecId).

So the problem is, if Recversion isn't being updated all the time, this method is useless since we aren't accurately capturing all updates.  The table we've noticed a problem with is InventSum.  The only thing I can see different from most other tables is the concurrency setting; InventSum is set to use Pessimistic concurrency.  Would this affect the behavior of when the Recversion value changes?  What else might cause this value not to update regularly?

The test:

I tested this out by recording the Recversion value of an InventSum record on a particular item in a given warehouse.  I then created a sales line for 100,000 of the item, which in turn updated the InventSum.ReservPhysical value.  Despite the change in the reserved amount on InventSum, the Recversion remained unchanged from its original value.  Picking the quantity also did not update the Recversion.  Posting a packing slip DID cause the Recversion to change.

So why the difference?"

[See the original question here](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/43058/why-doesn-t-recversion-always-change-on-record-update/567799)

Answer (score 0):

I've added "modifiedDateTime" to the InventSum table and altered the method: InventUpdateOnhand.sqlUpdateInventSumStrSQLServer() - the line:

> str                 sqls_base                    = 'UPDATE %1 SET %2
> FROM (SELECT %3 FROM %4 WHERE %5 GROUP BY %6) AS %7 WHERE %8';

changed to

> str                 sqls_base                    = 'UPDATE %1 SET %2,
> modifiedDateTime = GETUTCDATE() FROM (SELECT %3 FROM %4 WHERE %5 GROUP
> BY %6) AS %7 WHERE %8';

Then added an index containing modifiedDateTime, DataAreaId in that order.
This has helped the data warehouse people a lot

Comment: You might want to add the information from the answer of the question you linked to that RecVersion does not change for some updates of InventSum, because they are done with a direct SQL statement. Also add that your change does not update RecVersion, but modifiedDateTime instead, which can then be used to control an incremental update of the data warehouse. Finally, add a link to this answer in the linked question so others can find it.

Comment: if someone wants to update the RecVersion they can do it the same place as where I update the modifiedDateTime. I have however not tested this. 
RecVersion is used on all tables that has concurrency set to optimistic. InventSum is set to pessimistic.
The reason why I am posting it here is that Microsoft does not allow me to answer the original question. So I can't do what you suggest.